# Calling non-decorated methods on decorator object

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

Suppose we have implemented the **Decorator Pattern** as in the image below. With the *CondimentDecorator* class, the *Beverage* class can be decorated. The methods `cost()` and `getDescription()` will take care for that.

[image]

When creating a decorated *Beverage* like below, calling the method *getName()* won't work on the decorated object. In order to make this work, this method should also be placed in the class *CondimentDecorator* and delegate the call to the composed *beverage* variable.

```
Beverage b = new Milk(new Espresso("A very nice espresso"));
b.getName() // returns null
```

When having a lot of methods which don't need decoration, all of these should also be placed in *CondimentDecorator* to simply delegate. So the question is: **What is a neat (generally accepted) way to solve this 'problem'?**

Comment: What is the exact problem by adding them into `CondimentDecorator` assuming that it is the Decorator base class (the implemented methods i.e., operation1(), etc.. exist in only one class)

Comment: The 'problem' is that all these methods (e.g. operation1()) should also be placed in the `CondimentDecorator` to just simply delegate, and when having many of such methods, it 'pollutes' the Decorater class in my opinion

Comment: If `operation1()` does not decorate anything why do you need to place it inside `CondimentDecorator`?

Comment: Because, suppose `operation1()` returns an attribute called `name` from the `Beverage` class, calling this method on an decorated object without delegating it to the composed `beverage` object does not work.

Comment: Per the diagram, `CondimentDecorator` is a subclass of `Beverage`, so calling the method `getName()` _will_ work on the decorated object.

Comment: I have implemented this example and however it seems like this would indeed work, it does not.

Answer (score 1):

The generally accepted approach to this 'problem' in a *statically typed* language like Java or C# (yes, C# is not quite statically typed, I know about DLR, and dynamic) is to have the decorated methods delegate to the decorated object **explicitly**. This solution has the obvious benefits of **simplicity** and **explicitness**.

In your example, if you don't override `getName` it means that you **want** to change the behaviour of the decorated object, which is exactly the purpose of the decorator pattern.

If you would choose to delegate to the decorated object *by default* then it would appear as if inheritance was broken, since CondimentDecorator inherits from Beverage but does not use the methods of base class.

Then, to change this behaviour, you would somehow need to define the methods that are not delegated to decorated object, but should work "as usual inheritance".
That would be not obvious and very messy.

That being said, what you want to achieve should be possible in Java.

For instance in .NET you could do this in the following ways, and I believe Java has something similar

1. By generating dynamic runtime proxies that use inheritance to dynamically modify the behaviour of the object, see [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/)
2. By using a MSIL rewriting technique that rewrites your itermediate code at compile time to modify it, for example see [Fody - Method decorator](https://github.com/Fody/MethodDecorator)

Additionally, check out how [prototypical inheritance works in JavaScript -](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model#Class-based_vs._prototype-based_languages) that behaviour is very similar to what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

In your case if only few operation1() it is ok to add a delegate call to CondimentDecorator. If only few call() needs decoration then could make a decorator when needed, like:
DecoratorFactory.make(new Milk(new Espresso("A very nice espresso"))).getDescription();

or

CondimentDecorator.getDescription(new Milk(new Espresso("A very nice espresso")));

Key: patterns serve you.